# Redirect www to non-www is loosing my other RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this code in my, .htaccess file.

My url is fine foodzite.dk/vis/1234567
When i enter www.foodzite.dk/vis/1234567 i want it to redirect to foodzite.dk/vis/1234567
but i redirects to foodzite.dk/shop.php?url=1234567

How is it i cant combine the to Rewrites?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^vis/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ show.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^postnr/([^/]*)$ postal.php?postal=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^by/([^/]*)$ city.php?city=$1 [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foodzite\.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://foodzite.dk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your redirect rule **before** your routing rule. Otherwise the URI gets routed to your php file, then the redirect rule gets applied and the URI is exposed:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foodzite\.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://foodzite.dk/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^vis/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ show.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^postnr/([^/]*)$ postal.php?postal=$1 [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^by/([^/]*)$ city.php?city=$1 [NC,L]
```

Additionally, your conditions only get applied to the immediately following rewrite rule, so the 2nd and 3rd don't have the same conditions. (Unless you wanted it to be that way).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foodzite.dk [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: don't you have it backwards, i want it to remove the www. from my url

Comment: Gotcha.  Then yes, you would basically want to add "www." to line 2 and remove "www." from line 3.